# Is it normal to have two different dependent assembly but have the same public key token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-assembly, strongname

System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives -> b03f5f7f11d50a3a

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe -> b03f5f7f11d50a3a

```
<dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I have this error:

> An assembly with the same identity '**System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives**,
>   Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**b03f5f7f11d50a3a**' has
>   already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

Comment: Very good article about strongly named assemblies can be found [here](https://www.csharp411.com/net-assembly-faq-part-3-strong-names-and-signing/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is normal; the key-token here is the thumbprint of the **key** used to strong-name the assembly - it isn't unique to the assembly itself (unless the library author created a key and only used it to sign one assembly). In the case of system assemblies, they are all usually signed by the same key (or small set of keys). `b03f5f7f11d50a3a` is a very well known key token - it is even mentioned in the ECMA-335 specification.

Comment: @ranielgarcia I'd start by enabling binary logging and using the msbuild binary log viewer, which has *huge* amounts of information about where things are coming from and why

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this error by removing the references of System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives in the project References section, but kept the nuget package installed

Use this link
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1539#issuecomment-427397310